# Align two blocks horizontally in one block using bootstrap (without using css)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This code doesnt work due to margin in bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row1 col-lg-3">
       <div class="row2 col-lg-1"></div>
       <div class="row2 col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the only thing you can use in css is height and border

```
.row1, .row2{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.row1{
    height: 150px;
}
.row2{
    height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve with the classes that you already put there, but here is what's happening.

[image]

When the screen is bigger than 1200px it will apply the classes that you added, which means the two divs will become columns like the case that you have.

But if the screen is less than 1200px the two css classes do not work, and you'll get this, which I think is what you're trying to achieve:

[image]

So you just have to remove the `col-lg-1` and it will work as you intended.